# AWS CodeBuild cannot print parameter store environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

I keep track of a number in parameter store, and access it during CodeBuild executions. The CodeBuild environment is a Windows machine. I would like to print the environment variable.

I've tried the following:

1. Print the environment variable as-is: `echo $NUMBER`
2. Assign the environment variable to another variable and print: `$TMP=$NUMBER; echo $TMP`
3. Echo the environment variable to a text file and print that text file: `Add-Content -Path number.txt -Value $NUMBER; Get-Content number.txt`

All of them will be printed as asterisks. It looks like CodeBuild will automatically try to censor environment variable it deems sensitive (maybe all parameter store variables? I couldn't find any documentation on this). This particular env variable is not sensitive and we would like to print it. Is there a possible way?

Comment: So you have some value in parameter store or environment variable? Its confusing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a value in Parameter Store. CodeBuild has a feature that is able to pull parameters from Parameter Store and store it as an environment variable. So I'm trying to print that environment variable. Thanks @Marcin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few months back, CodeBuild implemented best-effort masking of secrets in the build logs. Since the majority use case of Parameter Store is to store sensitive information like passwords, CodeBuild is masking that from build logs. When the values being set as secrets are common strings like numbers or a common word, that will get masked throughout the logs.

Our suggestion for using simple environment variables would be to go with the plain text environment variables, as opposed to Parameter Store or Secrets Manager. Parameter Store and Secrets Manager values will get masked, when the same string is found in the log.

Security is usually not a friend of convenience, so apologies for this but avoiding the leaking of secrets is the primary concern here.

This will be documented properly in the docs soon.

### Edit1:

As per my tests, if the Param store variable has the value "ABC", then in the logs anywhere you have "ABC" (even if it is in any other innocent variable) it will be masked.

I guess we are back to square one with this, please use the CLI to obtain the value directly (for a secret value, highly recommend to continue using the buildspec 'parameter-store' construct):

```
  - MY_VAR=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name BUILD_NUM --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)
  - echo $MY_VAR
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @shariqmaws. We chose to use Parameter Store because the purpose of the parameter is versioning of an application, and we need to keep track of it. It's not a constant, and will be incremented with every build. Could you recommend another way of going about this? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the exact value in the Param store (if its not a secret)

Comment: It'll always be a natural number, let's say `6`. Thanks @shariqmaws.

Comment: It gets incremented with every build. We are using this instead of the built-in CodeBuild number in case we need to recreate the CodeBuild instance and don't want the build number to reset to 1.

Comment: Please see Edit1.

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion. It still prints as asterisks unfortunately. We may resort to using CodeBuild's built in build version. The only reason we were avoiding this because we don't want duplicate versions if we were to create a new CodeBuild. But we can just add to it manually during build.

Comment: Probably because you did not comment out the "parameter-store:" construct?

Comment: Oh! I was being a major idiot. Yup you're right. Thank you so much!